# Maximum update depth exceeded message in react js

Tags: reactjs

The message thrown is:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Other messages include:

> Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `width`.

and:

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

and:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `border` supplied to `Box`

I believe that the important error is the first one.

Is there an issue with this code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grommet,Button, TextInput,Text,Box} from 'grommet';
import { Cursor } from 'grommet-icons';
import Todolist from './components/comtodo';

const theme = {
global: {
font: {
family: 'Roboto',
size: '16px',
height: '20px',
},
},
};
const border={
side:'solid',
color:'brand',
size:'medium',
};




class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
todo:['asd'],
}
this.add = this.add.bind(this);

};

add(){
const todoinput = document.getElementById('todoinput').value;
const statetodo = this.state.todo;
statetodo.push(todoinput);
this.setState({todo:statetodo})

};


render() {
const list = this.state.todo.map((elem,id) => {
return(
<Box  border={border} margin="small" background="brand" align="center" alignContent="center" alignSelf="center" >
<li style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>
<Text weight="bold" size="xlarge" color="light-1">{id+1}- </Text>
<Text color="accent-1" size="large"> {elem}</Text><br/>
<Button > X </Button>
</li>
</Box>
)

});
return (
<div className="App">
<Grommet theme={theme} >
<br/>
<div style={{width:"25%",margin:"0 auto" , textAlign:"center"}}>
<TextInput size="medium" id="todoinput"  style={{margin:"0 auto"}}  >
</TextInput>
<br/>
<Button label='Add Todo' color="accent-1" onClick={this.add} alignSelf="center" width="10%" 
alignSelf="center" width icon={<Cursor/>} >    
</Button>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<Todolist list={list}/>

</Grommet>
</div>
);
}
}

export default App;
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Todolist extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div style={{width:"25%",margin:"0 auto" , textAlign:"center"}}>
            {this.props.list}
        </div> 
        )
    }
}
export default Todolist;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Grommet is handling the custom Button click internally but here is my take on all the issues.
You should also format the code better as it will help others to debug faster

1. Replace

`<Button label='Add Todo' color="accent-1" onClick={this.add} alignSelf="center" width="10%" alignSelf="center" width icon={<Cursor/>} ></Button>`

with

```
<Button label='Add Todo' color="accent-1" onClick={() => this.add()} alignSelf="center" width="10%" alignSelf="center" icon={<Cursor/>} ></Button>
```

I know you have already bound the add function, but give this a try.
This should also fix the second error (You had an extra width attribute)

2. Add attribute key to li inside map

`<li key={id} style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>`

3. Remove border attribute in the element Box. Dont think it is supported